# Rstudio code executing out of order with break point and ctrl-Enter?

Tags: r, rstudio

To replicate the issue, first create a script file and source it with:

```
Mathtest1 <- function (array1, mult)
{
  a1 = array1
  a2 = a1 * mult
  a3 = a2 + a1
  a4 = a3 - a1
  a5 = a4 * mult
  return(a5)
}
```

Then source this file (source on save or any way you like)

Then run the following from another cript file or console.

```
c1 = c(1:10)
c2 = c1
c2 = Mathtest1(c1,2)
print(c2)
```

The output should be:

```
c2 = Mathtest1(c1,2)
> print(c2)
 [1]  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
```

Now create a break point anywhere in the Mathtest1 function and debugsource (or not).

Now if you run the 5 lines from a file with Ctrl-Enter or the console I get:

```
> c2 = Mathtest1(c1,2)
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]> print(c2)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
Browse[1]> n
debug at ~/RStudio/Test1/Test1.R#5: a4 = a3 - a1
Browse[2]>
```

I expect the same print output after the function competes after the break.

The issue is that it executes the print(c2) line before the c2 = Mathtest1(c1,2) line finishes.

If the script file is sourced, then it does indeed wait for the break point to complete before finishing. So the issue is strictly with the console or Ctrl-Enter which makes debugging nearly impossible.

This occurs with R 3.5.3 and 3.6.1 with Rstudio 1.2.1335 and it did not happen before.

I do not know how to make break points in the Rgui so unfortunately I cannot test if the Rgui shows the same behavior.

Is there any way to always force in order execution?

Comment: For you, is this the same issue, posted by me, that this one [github rstudio/rstudio #4637: debugger step by step not in good order (1.2)](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4637) ?

Comment: I think you are right. Looks to be the same issue. Also, I don't think it is bound to step by step as I am seeing inconsistent results in a loop which would make sense if the function keeps executing without waiting for a slower sub-function to finish. Thanks.